# Django OneToOneField - in which model should I put it?

Tags: django, one-to-one

Let's assume that we have the following models.

```
class A(Model): pass
class B(Model): pass
```

Then there is no difference between:

In model A: `b = OneToOneField(B, related_name=A.__name__)`

and

in model B: `a = OneToOneField(A, related_name=B.__name__)`

So what questions should I ask myself to decide whether to put OTO in one model or another. I mean like has-a, is-a and so on.

Answer (score 47):

There actually is a difference in where you put the one-to-one field, because deletion behaves differently.  When you delete an object, any other objects that had one-to-one relationships referencing that object will be deleted. If instead you delete an object that contains a one-to-one field (i.e. it references other objects, but other objects are not referencing back to it), no other objects are deleted.

For example:

```
class A(models.Model):
    pass

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.OneToOneField(A)
```

If you delete A, by default B will be deleted as well (though you can override this by modifying the `on_delete` argument on the `OneToOneField` just like with [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete)).  Deleting B will not delete A (though you can change this behavior by overriding the `delete()` method on B).

Getting back to your initial question of has-a vs. is-a, if A has a B, B should have the one-to-one field (B should only exist if A exists, but A can exist without B).

Comment: Note this assumes `on_delete=CASCADE`, which was the default [before Django 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/releases/2.0/#features-removed-in-2-0).

Answer (score 10):

`OneToOneField`s are really only for two purposes: 1) inheritance (Django uses these for its implementation of MTI) or 2) extension of a uneditable model (like creating a `UserProfile` for `User`).

In those two scenarios, it's obvious which model the `OneToOneField` goes on. In the case of inheritance, it goes on the child. In the case of extension it goes on the only model you have access to.

With *very* few exceptions, any other use of a one-to-one should really just be merged into one single model.

Comment: What about table locking? If we were to separate specific data (such as a salary table from an Employee table), we could use `select_for_update` on the Employee table without locking the salary information. Correct?

Comment: Another valid use-case for a `OneToOneField` would be when a field is moved into a separate model as an alternative to `QuerySet.defer()`, as suggested in the *Note* in the [defer() documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#defer): "... the best choice you can make is to normalize your models and put the non-loaded data into a separate model ..."

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I needed OneToOneField to prevent **circular dependency** (inheritance use):

```
Model A:
  ...
  current_choice = models.ForeignKey(B)

Model B:
  ...
  parent = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

That means, A needs B to be defined. Not a good database convention for bootstrapping. 
Instead I did:

```
Model A:
  ...

Model B:
  ...
  parent = models.ForeignKey(A)

Model C:
  parent = models.OneToOneField(A)
  current_choice = models.ForeignKey(B)
```

With respect to example from [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/), you can also have clean queries like: p1.restaurant.place.restaurant.place... This is madness.

Comment: Why you did not realise this behaviour by simply using the *related_name* on the foreign key? So on Model A you could do `current_choice = models.ForeignKey(B, related_name='parent')` and then on every instance of B (`b = B.objects.first()`) you can do `b.parent` to fetch the related A-object.

Comment: Well, `related_name` is not necessarily one-to-one but used as a set query most of the time, so you need check for count etc. Example above is rather an immediate query as it has been forced to have a single result only.