# Organising complicated Django models

Tags: database, django, django-models

I'm currently building an app for a client where each record has a large number of different pieces of information (around 50-60 fields) associated with it.

I want to break the model up into sections so that the data is a bit more structured.

My first attempt is to do something like this:

```
class Program(models.Model):
    class BookingInformation(models.Model):
        program = models.OneToOneField('Program', related_name='booking_information')

        producer = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
        producer_phone = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

        ...

    class Editorial(models.Model):
        program = models.OneToOneField('Program')

        series = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

        ...
```

I have 5 or so sections and some of them are nested.

This way I could have a program object and do `program.booking_information.producer` to get at that field. Also I can more easily use `ModelForm` to have separate forms for each of the sections (something that I'd like).

The difficulty arises when I create the object. Because when I create a Program object, the Program.BookingInformation object doesn't exist yet, and I can't make it without first saving the Program (so it gets a primary key). And then I read things like [this which appear to discourage the use of OneToOneFields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9807155/382749) when they're not absolutely neccessary.

Should I put the whole lot into one model? It seems messy to me to have one big table with all these fields, but then I'm fairly new to this database stuff.

Comment: [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) - Flat is better than nested. Also, I doubt if nested models are really necessary here.

Comment: @karthikr would you care to elaborate why?

Comment: No matter how complex the models are, I dont see a need for nested models. You can rethink it and build a flat structure. It is hard to tell what to change without knowing much about the application/seeing the models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a database level, it is a bad idea to use separate tables for data that is one-on-one related to a single model. Querying in such separate tables would require twice the amount of queries and thus slow down your application and complicate the use of these models. In general you wan't to have as few queries as possible.

What is possible, is to divide the different 'groups' of data into separate abstract models that you all inherit from:

```
class BookingInformation(models.Model):
    # fields

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Program(BookingInformation, Editorial, etc.):
    pass
```

It might make your code just a tiny bit more readable, but I don't really see a clear advantage to this, and if you somehow require more advanced logic in your models, you might run into issues. I would suggest you to put everything into a single class and make a visual distinction between the groups with blank lines and comments and the like.

To get the separate forms you want, you can specify multiple `ModelForm` classes that each have their own `fields` option defined:

```
class BookingInformationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['producer', 'producer_phone', etc]
```

This would require most, if not all fields of the model to have `null=True` or `blank=True`, depending on the particular field, to prevent issues when you create a model with a form that has just a subset of the fields of the model.

Comment: I was thinking about the multiple inheritance from abstract classes, but I agree, it'll get messy if I need to write methods that look at data from different parts. Huge table it is!